# SSAS error when executing query: "File system error: The record ID is incorrect."

Tags: ssas

I have an ASP web application that executes MDX queries using SSAS. I have started getting the following error on some queries.

> File system error: The record ID is incorrect. Physical file: \?\C:\Program     Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Temp\NLevelDecodeStore_{E81C53D3-9A74-11E1-B75A-00155D1E7701}.tmp. Logical file: .

It's strange that it's only started happening now as I have never had the problem before. The error also only occurs under my web application, if I run it under SSMS the query returns with the results immediately.

The web application runs under the Network Service account, so thinking it could be a security issue I tried running the app under an administrator account and the query completed successfully. I also found that  if I add the Network Service account to the list of Server Administrators (right-click on the server in SSMS, properties, and then the security tab) then the query will also complete. I'd rather not do either of these however due security risks.

Edit:
The problem with the above solution is that SSAS role security is not applied to server administrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out that I was in some instances I was using a Dimension Data allowed member set expression of

```
[Customer].[Customer].AllMembers
```

The AllMembers function includes calculated members which was what caused the seemingly unrelated error. Changing to .Members to exclude calc members solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this message :

> File system error: The record ID is incorrect. Physical file: . Logical file:

It happen when your dimension file is growth over 4GB. 
And you choose PROCESS UPDATE method to process dimensions. 
I have errors issued  and found on google search , 
to solve problem is FULL Process Cube for a moment. And I don't have a permanent solution to fix this problem.

Fixed wit this solution :

http://mssqlbase.blogspot.com/2010/04/process-olap-dimensions-error-file.html

http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2007/04/29/SSAS-ProcessUpdate---Too-much-of-a-good-thing.aspx